# Why 100/1000 is not 0.10 in swift palyground?

Tags: swift, floating-point, double, decimal, swift-playground

I am facing a problem where I am not getting values of decimal places here is the code that I used to run in Swift Playground

```
print(100/1000)
print(Float(100/1000))
```

Expected Output :

```
0.10
0.10
```

Actual Output:

```
0
0.0
```

[image]

Comment: You're doing integer divisions, you're getting integer result

Comment: Think: `print(100/1000); print(Float(100/1000)); print(Float(100)/1000); print(100/Float(1000)); print(Float(100)/Float(1000))`. 5 "possibilities". Integer can't have decimal, right? If so, Float(someInteger), where `someInteger` is `100/1000`, and you got before 0, that's normal to have 0.0, because that's `Float(0)`, no?

Answer (score 0):

Because of this:

```
let variable = 100/1000
print(type(of: variable))
// prints Int
```

Comment: @VarunNaharia because `100/1000`, the integer division equals 0. `Float(0)` equals `0.0`

Comment: 100/1000 = 0, so Float(0) = 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
print(100.0 / 1000.0)
print(Float(100) / Float(1000))
```

So in order to get a floating point result you need to divide floating point numbers instead of two integers